# Rules for improvising intermediate notes in basso continuo

Tags: theory, counterpoint, baroque-period, figured-bass

When realizing figured bass, passing notes in the bass are analyzed quite thoroughly in literature (e.g. The Art of Accompaniment from a Thorough Bass). However, I cannot find any information or rules on improvising passing notes in the higher registers. However, I do see it happen. For example, here in this realization of measure 7 of SWV 289:

[image: Realization of measure 7 from SWV 289]

To me, it seems like it is desirable to have those transition notes since they connect upper voice of the BC. However, here it does double the soprano which I thought was undesirable from the bass.

I have the following questions about these notes:

- Is the realization above even any good?
- Is there literature (perhaps only practical) about these notes?
- Are there rules they should obey?

To give some more examples:

This is a really frivolous realization with many notes added.
[image: busy arrangement]
In the following, you have a D# added in the second measure of the alto. Otherwise there would be a consecutive unison with the bass. So I might infer from this a rule saying you can add a half step down between two notes.
[image]

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the question. There are no improvised passing notes here, just a doubling of the soprano (in the same register), which is fine — even expected. I'm also not seeing where there would be parallel fifths with the bass. Am I missing something in the BC?

Comment: @Aaron Oh you're absolutely right; it's not a very good example. I think the question still stands though because there's more pieces which do actually have these improvised passing notes. I have added two such examples to make the question clearer.

Comment: The first example isn't a particularly good realization, no.  It is not in fact expected to double the soprano; it's rather poor form.  What is the source of the "frivolous" realization?

Comment: @phoog It's one measure of an example of the book the Thoroughbass method from Keller. Specifically from chapter 5, where they discuss 1700-1750 with also pieces from Handel and Bach.